# the error with gulp browsersync

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

I have some gulpfile.js below and something is wrong. To be exact, when I type gulp in terminal there comes and error:
'browserSync' errored after 614 μs
[20:52:42]

```
   TypeError: args.cb is not a function
   at Object.init 
   at Gulp.<anonymous> 
   at module.exports 
   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask 
   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep 
   at Gulp.Orchestrator.start 
   at Gulp.<anonymous> 
   at module.exports 
   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask 
   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep
```

My gulpfile.js

```
            var gulp = require('gulp');
            var sass = require('gulp-sass');
            var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
            var reload = browserSync.reload;
            var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
            var sassdoc = require('sassdoc');
            var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');

            var src = {
            html:['./app/index.html'],
            js:['./app/js/app.js']
            };

            var sassOptions = {
                errLogToConsole: true,
                outputStyle: 'expanded'
            };

            var autoprefixerOptions = {
                browsers: ['last 15 versions', '> 5%', 'Firefox ESR']
            };

            jshint: {
              options: {
                node: true
              }
            }

            //tasks
            gulp.task('default', ['watch'], function(){
                gulp.start('watch');
            });

            gulp.task('lint', function() {
                return gulp.src('./app/js/app.js')
                        .pipe(jshint())
                        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
            });

            gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
                browserSync.init({
                    server: {
                        baseDir: 'app',
                        index: 'index.html'
                    },
                    port: 3000,
                    open: true
                });
            });

            gulp.task('sass', function() {
                return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
                    .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
                    .pipe(autoprefixer(autoprefixerOptions))
                    .pipe(sassdoc())
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
                    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
                        stream: true
                    }))
            });

            gulp.task('html', function(){
                gulp.src(src.html)
                    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
                        stream: true
                    }))
            });

            gulp.task('js', function(){
                gulp.src(src.js)
                    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
                        stream: true
                    }))
            });

            gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function(){
                gulp.watch('./app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
                gulp.watch('./app/**/*.html', ['html']);
                gulp.watch('./app/js/app.js', ['js']);
              // Other watchers
            })
```

The thing is everything is working fine except it's not opening index.html file directly, just empty browser window. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the error and opening the index.html file directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should have `watch` both as a dependancy of `default` and also call it in the function.

Maybe replace `default` with just this:

```
//tasks
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function(done) {
            browserSync.init({
                server: {
                    baseDir: 'app',
                    index: 'index.html'
                },
                port: 3000,
                open: true
            });
            done();
        });
```

Just a quick guess, that is how mine is set up and it works.  Your error message indicates it may be looking for a call back function.

Comment: i tried all tasks one by one, the 'default' task is the one that is not working, but why?